# Is it possible to create separate buttons for each console.log line in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api

**What are the details of your problem?**

I am fetching campaign names from a marketing api using the following code. This code prints all campaign names to the console.

javascript code:

```
function fetchCampaigns(){ 
  account.read([AdAccount.Fields.name])
  .then((account) =>{
      return account.getCampaigns([Campaign.Fields.name], { limit: 20} ) // fields array and params
  })
  .then((result) =>{
      campaigns = result
      let campaign_names = campaigns.forEach((campaign) => console.log(campaign.name))
  }).catch(console.error);
}
```

**console output:**
campaignName1
campaignName2
campaignName3
...
campaignName20

**What did you try and what were you expecting?**
I would like to create a different button with a specific id for each of the campaign names but so far, I just get all of the console.log text on one button instead of being split into different buttons. Is there a way to do this in javascript without having to create a bunch of buttons in html?

javascript code:

```
window.console = {
  log: function(str){
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    button.type = "button";
    button.className = "button";
    button.value = `${str}`;
    button.appendChild(document.createTextNode(button.value));
    document.getElementById("artist-button").appendChild(button);
  }
}
```

html:

```
<button type="button" id="campaign-button" class="button" float="left"></button>
```

Note: Not trying to overwrite console.log, I am trying to use the values I get from console.log(campaign.name) (the campaign names) and assign each line outputted to the console to different buttons.

Comment: Overriding a built-in like `console.log()` is most often frowned upon. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I like how OP did that and then asked a question like it's the most obvious thing in the world that `console.log()` should create buttons.

Comment: But as weird this code is, it [should work](https://codepen.io/DallogFheir/pen/wvQNrjd). You have to show more. And what does button with ID `campaign-button` have to do with any of this?

Comment: create the buttons in the forEarch loop instead of calling `console.log`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I needed had to do with the window.console code.

```
let id = 0;
window.console = {
  log: function (str) {
       var button = document.createElement("button");
       button.innerHTML = `${str}`;
       var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
       body.appendChild(button);
       button.id = id;
       id++;
       button.addEventListener ("click", function() {
          alert("did something");
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).